# Passing data from VBScript to XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm completely new to both VBScript and XSL manipulation, but am in a position where I need to do some work on such files... So there's a chance this might not even be possible, or that I'm misunderstanding how the current code works, or whatever.

But from what I gather, currently there's an XSL file that transforms a list of news articles from an XML file into valid HTML. It also limits the number though, so it only ever displays three articles. It does this using `<xsl:if test="position() &lt; ($NumberOfArticles + 1)">htmlgoeshere</xsl:if>` where `$NumberOfArticles` is defined earlier with `<xsl:param name="NumberOfArticles" select="3" />`.

This XSL is called using the following VBScript:

```
Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Call xmlhttp.Open("GET", url, False)
Call xmlhttp.send

set feedxml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
feedxml.async = false
feedxml.load(xmlhttp.ResponseBody)

set feedxsl = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
feedxsl.async = false
feedxsl.load(Server.MapPath("xsl/" & stylesheet))

FeedContent = feedxml.transformNode(feedxsl)
```

where `url` is the URL of the XML file and `stylesheet` is the filename of the XSL file.

I also have a VBScript variable called `NumberOfArticles` that relies on user input. Is there a way to pass this variable into the XSL file such that it will set `$NumberOfArticles` to it, rather than the value being hardcoded as `3`? So then the user can decide to display more or less?

Comment: Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762312(v=vs.85).aspx which shows you how to use the "addParameter" method. The example is in jscript, not vbscript, but it should not be too hard to convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a global `xsl:param` in your stylesheet, meaning put that `<xsl:param name="NumberOfArticles" select="3" />` as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` (respectively `xsl:transform`). Then you need to make sure you load the stylesheet as e.g.

```vb
Dim xsl, template, processor

Set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0")
xsl.async = False
xsl.load Server.MapPath("xsl/" & stylesheet)

Set template = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XslTemplate.6.0")
Set template.stylesheet = xsl

Set processor = template.createProcessor

processor.addParameter "NumberOfArticles", NumberOfArticles    
processor.input = xmlhttp.responseXML
processor.transform

FeedContent = processor.output
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I seem to be getting a `Object doesn't support this property or method` error referring to the line `processor = template.createProcessor`...

Comment: Does it work with `processor = template.createProcessor()`? I am afraid my VBScript skills are limited, I mainly tried to remember how I do it in JScript and then transcribe that to VBScript, but admittedly my knowledge of precise VBScript syntax rules is not good so the snippet is hopefully showing which objects and which methods to use but might need some correction on syntax details.

Comment: It turns out the error message was trying to mislead me. All I needed to do was use `Set` before the line in question. Thanks for the help, it's working as I desired now!

Comment: @Cal Note that if your XSLT's output is supposed to be the entire response that you want to send to the client, you may use `inputNode.transformNodeToObject(xsl, Response)`, which streams the XSLT output to the client without an intermediate step. In your case, the `inputNode` would be the `xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement`. (See documentation on the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766561(v=vs.85).aspx)